# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

So let me start from the top. I have made a console app that will run daily with the use of a scheduled task. The console app works and has been tested. My issue is when I take the `.exe` and `.exe.config` from the bin I am moving these to a separate server changing the config to contain relevant connection strings but when the `.exe` runs I am getting the below error:

```
Application: xxx.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String, System.Data.Common.DbAsyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Data.SqlClient.RunBehavior, Boolean, System.String)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
   at Dmc.V1.BatchTasks.DestinationMarketingEntityTableAdapters.HotelCodesTableAdapter.GetData()
   at Dmc.V1.BatchTasks.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: please check the .NET Framework version installed on the remote pc.

Comment: goto control panel->add/remove programs: there you can see which version is installed on the pc.

Comment: I can see 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4' and 'Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5' is this helpful?

Comment: is is on remote machine right, please check the .net veraion on your local pc also and let m know.

Comment: OK so remote machine I can see  'Microsoft .NET Framework 4' and 'Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1' and on my local 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1' and 'Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5' and 'Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2'

Comment: it is a compatibility issue, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran in to this issue and for me it turned out the user my app was logging to the database with didn't have execute permission on the stored procedure I was trying to running.

My app was targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2 and my app runs as a scheduled task. I got the same error message

```
Application: xxx.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
```

If there have been recent changes to the database or to the connection string being used by the app check for a possible database permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me as a `.NET Framework` `compatibility` issue.

**Problem :** you have developed your application in your local machine with `.NET Framework 4.5` and running the same on remote pc having `.NET Framework 4.0`.

Note : if you target your application to run on `Higher` Version of `.NET Framework` it wont run on below versions.

**Solution :** you need to target it to .NET `Framework 4.0` to run on remote pc.

**Step 1:**  right click on `project` - select `properties`

**Step 2:**  change the `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework  4.5` to `.NET Framework 4`.

**Step 3:**  now **rebuild** your application and deploy.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I will let you know if this works!:-)

Comment: No unfortunately it did not work thanks for trying to help though

Comment: v4.0.30319 is CLR's version which is different from .net framework's version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have kept Console.Readline() at the end of the program. Please remove it and try again. It would work well.

Thanks